# Accessing a remote folder location via IIS virtual directory mapping

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

We have hosted a C# Web API web application in IIS and let’s assume that its host URL is http://abcd.com. Using this application we can upload images and they are saved in a pre-configured folder location outside the IIS hosted folder. Let’s assume that the image folder path is D:\Uploads\Images. The images in the given folder location should be accessible via the application as hyperlinks such as http://abcd.com/pictures/1234.jpg. To implement this functionality we have created a virtual directory in IIS called ‘pictures’. The virtual directory was mapped to D:\Uploads\Images and the physical folder path was given the full control access to all the users. When trying to access the images using the URL e.g. http://abcd.com/pictures/1234.jpg we get a permission issue saying access is forbidden. Are there any other configuration changes to be made? Appreciate your support.

Comment: What are the permissions on the image files themselves?

Comment: @NetMage - Image files are also given full-control access for all the users. The folder, D:\Uploads\Images are given full-control read write access in a way which the same access is applied for all the sub folders and files within the particular folder. By the way do we need to grant any permission to the virtual directory (here it's 'pictures') as well?

Comment: As far as I know there are no separate permissions for a virtual directory (mine don't show any). There are `Authorization Rules` and the default should be `All Users`.